# A good, free, simple, non-"trial" local SMTP server for development?

Tags: smtp

I'm running Windows Vista on my development machine... tried four SMTP servers so far (2 crashed, 2 turned out to be trial ware after being promoted as "free"). So I don't have IIS6 SMTP available.

Do you know any simple, hassle-free SMTP server that I can use? I need absolutely no bells and whistles. All it needs to do is listen on port 25 and send off emails.

Help?

Comment: The SO censor strikes again. THIS IS CONSTRUCTIVE!!!!!!

Comment: [Haraka](http://haraka.github.io/) should be mentioned here. Node.js based.

Comment: nice close! here's an idea: change the answers below to some terribly incorrect ones. that will teach us :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Mercury Mail](http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercwin.htm)

Comment: This is also part of XAMPP as well.

Comment: I've successfully used http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/ today.

Comment: and if I use this free server what is the value I put in the php.ini for SMTP variable ?

Answer (score 5):

[Free SMTP Server](http://www.softstack.com/freesmtp.html) is a simple and small SMTP server. It always forwards emails to recipents. That's all.

Comment: It has limitation **10 mails per day**

Comment: Better option would be to use http://www.hmailserver.com/

Comment: I use this for development purposes as well

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Lamson](http://lamsonproject.org/), an SMTP server in Python.

Comment: definitely more production-ready than the good old pysmtp I suggested - thanks for the useful pointer!

Answer (score 2):

You can hardly get freer or simpler than [pysmtp](http://www.hare.demon.co.uk/pysmtp.html)

Comment: +1 but pysmtp has been has been superseded by the smtpd module in the standard library. See http://docs.python.org/library/smtpd.html

Answer (score 1):

Install sendmail in a virtual ubuntu machine and send email through that.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows XP, there's a "SMTP service" in the IIS category under 'Add/Remove Windows Components' - not sure if Vista has that too.

Comment: Poster mentions that this isn't available.

Comment: This feature was removed from Vista.  It's still available in Server 2008.