# Configure SMTP capabilities on my Apache server

Tags: php, apache, email, smtp

I have an Apache, PHP, MySQL combo running on my Windows 8 machine. I want to send mails using the PHP mail function but then learnt that I need an SMTP server configured. How to do this? I have Outlook installed if that info is of any use.

Comment: Please ask your question on http://serverfault.com/. stackoverflow only allows questions about software code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need a lightweight, free, windows SMTP server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076/need-a-lightweight-free-windows-smtp-server)

Comment: The SMTP service is unrelated to Apache & MySQL. It's a separate service entirely.

Comment: More recommendations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932679/a-good-free-simple-non-trial-local-smtp-server-for-development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a library called "swiftmail" which can contact an external SMTP server (like gmail) and do the job. Turns out having a local SMTP server wasn't required after all.

Here is the link: http://swiftmailer.org/